# jQuery Esc Keypress bind

Tags: jquery, keypress

I'd like to add a bind in which the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key will slide my panel back up. Here is my jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".port-link-container").click(function () {
        $("div.slider-panel").slideUp("slow");
    });

    $("#wr").click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 450 }, 'slow');
        $("div#wr-large").slideDown("slow");
    });

    $("#sema").click(function () {
        $("div#sema-large").slideDown("slow");
    });

    $(".slider-close").click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
        $("div.slider-panel").slideUp("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
#pannel
{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#ddd;
}
```

```
<div id="pannel"></div>
```

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){

    if(e.keyCode === 27)
        $("#pannel").slideToggle();

});
```

Try that?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VE6un/3)

Comment: @WilliamGeorge It didn't like the keyup event being bound to the body. :P binding it to the document object works though. Updated code.

Comment: For dynamically loaded scripts (e.g. with AJAX) you may need to put it in this way: `$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {...`

Answer (score 4):

Try this with keyup event

```
$(function(){

  $(document).keyup(function(e){

    if(e.which == 27)
    {
      $("div.slider-panel").slideUp("slow");
    }
  });
});
```