# Javascript Side Content keep appearing after Toggle the Style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a Side menu for my responsive website. I'm not that good with JavaScript but it is working! (so far)

My problem is that, I'm toggling the `<nav>` class to make it appear and dissapear from the left side. The button to click is outside the `<nav>` content and the button to close is a simple text inside the `<nav>` content.

So, my HTML looks like this:

```
<nav id="nav-slide" class="nav-slide">
        Side Content <br>
        <a href="#" class="close" id="close-button">Close</a>
</nav>
```

That's the nav that I'm trying to Toggle. The button to open should be this image:

```
<a href="#"><img id="menu-icon" src="images/menu-icon.svg"/></a>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-slide {
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
background-color: #3f3f3f;
z-index: 99;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 20px;
color:#fff;
margin-left: -100%;
transition: margin 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.nav-open {
margin-left: 0px;
transition: margin 200ms ease-in-out;
}
```

and my JAVASCRIPT:

```
$("#menu-icon").click(function(){
    $("#nav-slide").toggleClass("nav-open");
});

$("#close-button").click(function(){
    $("#nav-slide").toggleClass("nav-slide");
});
```

Is working so far! But when I click on Close text, and after closing the `<nav>` it keeps displaying `<nav>` content like this image:

[Image with example of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv6Im.png)

Any way to solve this?

Comment: hey,try this althought the animation is different the solution works!!
https://jsfiddle.net/57t0rLfy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuerys [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) does add a new class to an item. If it already has that class, it will remove it from that item. So while your nav's base class is nav-slide, toggle nav-open only (not both). Here's a slightly different, basic example of an animated side-nav:

```js
$('button').on('click', function (e) {
  $('.menu').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: tomato;
  
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.menu.open {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<button>menu</button>
<div class="menu">
  <button>close</button>
</div>
```

Edit: Here is a pen of your example:
http://codepen.io/wilmaknattern/pen/xZXMaW

Comment: Hi there @Thomas thanks for your answer. but what if it's not two buttons with the same name, but <div> or <img> with links?

Comment: @Eugenio It's quite the same. Just make sure to toggle `nav-open` only.

Comment: @Eugenio: I added a pen with the code from your example.

Comment: thank you very much Thomas! I think I'm understanding more now:D!

Comment: Hello @Thomas, another question, if I want to use also the esc button to close the  slide?

Comment: @Eugenio Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969788/jquery-esc-keypress-bind

Comment: Thank you very much! now is working @Thomas , the problem is, now is working to open and close the slide. Should only close it. any way to prevent it to re-open the tab if I click the esc key twice? thanks for all!

Comment: @Eugenio You need to `removeClass` on the ESC binding. I updated the pen: http://codepen.io/wilmaknattern/pen/xZXMaW

Comment: Is because I have now two slides, one form left and another form the right, the left one is the menu and the right one another menu for flags (pick language) now if I press esc, it's closing one menu and open the other, and if I click again will do the opposite again. and if both menus remain closed and you click on esc they both will open again

Comment: @Eugenio No problem :)